# Mixed codebase JS and TypeScript Vue SFC, how can I make sure typescript-eslint doesn't lint the non 'lang="ts"' files and only use default eslint?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

Sorry if that sounds a bit confusing. But I have this codebase with legacy code written in Vue SFC using plain JavaScript. We're redesigning the entire application so we've started looking into writing the new components in TypeScript.

I set up the new TypeScript-based application using @vue-cli and when migrating the old JS components, it looks like `@typescript-eslint` is linting the JS parts of Vue SFC.

How can I override this and make sure that `@typescript-eslint` is only for those Vue files that have `lang="ts"` in it.

Comment: You can use `.eslintignore` and ignore the files/folders manually based on pattern matching. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code